# Resize GNU screen windows with a mouse

Tags: mouse, gnu-screen

I love the way I can resize windows in vim using the mouse.

Is it possible to do the same in GNU screen?  If not, is there an alternative to screen that supports this functionality?

Comment: You can resize vim windows with the mouse? I guess the mouse is the furthest thing from my mind when I'm using vim.

Comment: as others asked before: are you referring to resizing of split windows? Such you get with C-a S ?

Answer (score 1):

I use screen all the time, and change the window size effortlessly, without an issue.   It's whatever command is running inside the screen that needs to be able to resize as well.

Comment: I believe the question is implicitly referring to split windows (`:split`)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Roy - I resize windows all the time, and I only run things in screen. In fact, I can't think of the last time I kept a terminal up for more than 1 minute that wasn't running screen permanently.

Even with Putty from a windows box, it works.

Even with Putty from a windows box, ssh'ed into localhost running cygwin/sshd, running screen, it works.

Maybe there's something in your .screenrc or even your shell's .rc file that's preventing resize?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/terminator/) is probably what you're looking for.

Note that I've never used GNU Screen or Terminator, so I'm relying on the following information:

1. According to the intro to [the Wikpedia article about GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_screen), it's main purpose is for showing "multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window".
2. The header on [Terminator's site on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/terminator/) says, "the main focus is arranging terminals in grids".
3. The screenshots seem to be displaying similar features.
4. I've read a little bit in passing when they've been mentioned on blogs, and heard a bit in podcast segments. My memory of what they said is also in agreement with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

GNU screen is completely oblivious of the mouse.

As is Vim, when it's running within a TTY emulator.

Comment: Vim supports using the mouse from a TTY emulator.  See `:help mouse` and `:help ttymouse` for details.

Comment: xterm-style mouse reporting writes (non-ASCII) characters to the TTY device. GNU/screen interprets all characters written to it, and translates them as appropriate, so it *could* be aware of the mouse in the same way Vim is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about resizing the split areas inside a window.
I agree that this is possible to do it in VIM with the mouse.
This is very handy.

I also would like this feature for *gnu screen*.

In the meantime, I recommend you to try the sweet extension [*Vim-shell*](http://www.wana.at/vimshell/), which enables you to have native shells embedded in VIM.

It's too bad it is no more maintained or merged within Vim itself.
You will have to compile it by hand on an older version of VIM (7.0).

Comment: You can also try Conque Shell. It's a vim plugin (not a patch) and works great for me: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771

Comment: God! This is just awesome...
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) knows about the mouse:

> tmux is a terminal multiplexer: it enables a number of terminals (or
>   windows), each running a separate program, to be created, accessed,
>   and controlled from a single screen. tmux may be detached from a
>   screen and continue running in the background, then later reattached.

Answer (score 0):

> X Window, by itself, generates borderless windows in fixed screen locations. It requires a "window manager" to add borders and buttons and the ability for users to resize and move the windows on screen. The Tabbed Window Manager (twm) has been the default X window manager, but more than three dozen others have been used, including AfterStep, Blackbox and Enlightenment. The KDE and GNOME user interfaces for Linux use Kwin and Metacity respectively as their window managers.

**Source:** http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/X+Window

Comment: please link to your source, repeat offenses will result in suspension. Thanks!